# Can anyone help to install Xamarin forms in visual studio 2015 community version for cross platform

Tags: xamarin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjV49.png)
This what I tried to do. Actually, i am trying to create windows application

Answer (score 0):

You have your portable project selected as your startup project.  Right click on the Windows project and select "Set as Startup".